# SSH X11 forwarding keystrokes are getting stuck

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, x11-forwarding

Using PuTTY with X11 forwarding and the VcXsrv server for Windows, I access a Linux machine on the wireless LAN. Any keystrokes I make get repeated multiple times as if the key was stuck, for example "linux" becomes "liiinuxxxxxx" on the remote textbox.

The remote server is running a standard Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and the PuTTY is configured to enable X11 and compression. How should I change the configurations to prevent this?

Thanks

Comment: Is the key always repeated the same number of times, or is it random?

Comment: It seems to be random.